# Left Bit Shift In C without extension

Tags: c

I was wondering how to get C to not extend my binary number when I bitshift to the left

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned int binary_temp = 0b0100;
    binary_temp = binary_temp << 2;
    printf("%d", binary_temp);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run that I want a return value of 0 since it has extended past the 4 digits I have, but right now it returns 16 (10000). How would I get C not to extend my number?

Edit: I would like to be able to work with the number in binary form so I need to have only 4 digits, and not just outputting the right number.

Comment: Note that the binary `0b0100` notation is a non-standard (GNU) extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "Work with the number in binary form"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, what do you recommend as standard to represent binary literals?

Comment: @Atique, the computer presumably represents *everything* in binary.  Use decimal, hexadecimal, or octal contstants.

Comment: There isn't a way to write binary constants in Standard C; you can use hexadecimal (`0x08`) or octal (`010`).  Normally, use hexadecimal unless you're working on Unix permissions.

Comment: @user2303605, Note you are using unsigned int which is usually 4 bytes. That's why it extends. There is no data type in c to represent precisely 4 bits. However, you can represent 1 byte using a type like char. To solve your problem you have to use masks as suggested by answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not extend your number but saves it as unsigned int type which is 4 bytes (32 bits) in size. You only fill the last 4 bits. To treat it as only 4 bits, use Bitwise AND with a Mask value. Here's example code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int binary_temp = 0b0100;
    binary_temp = (binary_temp << 2) & 0b1111;
    printf("%u", binary_temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bitwise `AND` the result with a 4 bit mask value:

```
binary_temp = (binary_temp << 2) & 0xF;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `0b` in standard C. You could use `4`.

```
unsigned int /* prepare for wtf identifier: */
             binary_temp = 4;
```

Left shifting by 2 is multiplying by 4. Why not?

```
binary_temp *= 4;
```

... and then reduce modulo 16?

```
binary_temp %= 16;
```

What sense is there to using binary operators, in this case? I see none.

The `%d` directive corresponds to an `int` argument, but the argument you're giving `printf` is an `unsigned int`. That's undefined behaviour.

```
printf("%u", binary_temp);
```

I'm sure whichever book you're reading will tell you about the `%u` directive.

Comment: It may be true that the notation is nonstandard, but the `0bXXXX` notation is available in both GCC and Clang, and is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Speaking of relevance: The question mentions C several times, but not gcc or clang. C is defined by the standard, not gcc or clang. There are no mentions of either of those implementations in the question. I think pointing out constraint violations is perfectly relevant, here...

Comment: Playing the standards game is hardly constructive here, don't you think?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII [Here](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_community:comp.lang.c:Portability_attitude) is my portability attitude. If you have any points that aren't addressed by that page, feel free to raise them [here, in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28597/room-for-modifiable-lvalue-and-richard-j-ross-iii). Otherwise, I hope you are able to see the light.